# ERRO AO ABRIR O CHROME PELO SELENIUM

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from tkinter import *

servico = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
navegador = webdriver.Chrome(service=servico)
navegador.get("https://portal.rhhealth.com.br/portal/")
navegador.maximize_window()
```

esta dando o erro abaixo.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Robo personalizado\Robo finalizado\teste.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .chrome.webdriver import WebDriver as Chrome  # noqa
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 19, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.chromium.webdriver import ChromiumDriver
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 21, in <module>        
    from selenium.webdriver.chromium.remote_connection import ChromiumRemoteConnection
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\remote_connection.py", line 19, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import RemoteConnection
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 27, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import exceptions
```

Answer (score -3):

Parece que o package 'urllib3' instalado no seu PC não é compatível com o selinium. Tente desinstalar o package e depois instala-lo novamente.
Usando pip, tente isso no seu terminal.

```
 pip uninstall urllib3
 pip install urllib3
```

Outra solução é usar um driver de navegador diferente, diferente do chrome. Como Firefox, Edge ou Safari.
Também é possível que o problema esteja relacionado à versão do navegador Chrome instalada em seu sistema. Você deve certificar-se de que a versão do chrome instalada em sua máquina é compatível com a versão do driver do chrome que você está usando.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).